# Hide Toolbar with CoordinatorLayout, but RecyclerView on a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-design-library, android-tablayout

I have an Activity with two tabs. Each tab contains a fragment with a `SwipeRefreshLayout` and a `RecyclerView` inside them.

In the Activity, I have a `CoordinatorLayout` with an `AppBarLayout` (with a `Toolbar` and a `TabLayout`) and a `ViewPager` for the Fragments.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zECm.jpg)

Now, what I want to achieve is: when the user scrolls in the fragments, the Toolbar, and not the tabs, hides, like in the Play Store.

In the examples that I have read over the Internet, the layout is very simple: they have the `RecyclerView` and the `Toolbar` inside the `CoordinatorLayout` on the same xml.

Then, they just write:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvToDoList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

And

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

So, I can't figure out how to do it.

My xml's are the following:

The Activity Layout is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main_drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/activity_main_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/color_primary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_main_tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/color_text_primary"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_tabs_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_nav_drawer_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/color_primary"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And the fragments are:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_coupons_swipe_refresh_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.github.yasevich.endlessrecyclerview.EndlessRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_coupons_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the `LinearLayout`s

Comment: And `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` on the `ViewPager`, not the `SwipeRefreshLayout`

Comment: Nope, didn't work :(.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Can you update your code and repost it.

Comment: `LinearLayout`s is plural because I was referring to the ones in your fragment layout **and** activity layout.

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw that. Let me check.

Comment: I just updated the code. Still not working. Thansk for your time

Comment: Well, I don't see any other problems. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Man, I faced the same problem. The problem is not in the code. I bet you are using old versions of the build tools and the libraries. Update them to the latest:

- buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1
- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0

In my case this worked like a charm! Good luck!

Comment: @LucasDaddiego, did you managed to try my solution? If it helped you, may I ask you to accept my answer as correct :)

Comment: Glad to know it helped :)

Comment: This solved my needs aswell! 
Just a tip for everybody who might be doing it wrong like me, this wiz-trick won't work if you (like me) are using a ListView instead of a RecyclerView.
As soon as I switched, everything went fine.

Answer (score 2):

For everyone using a Scrollview in a Fragment, like me, I suggest you to use android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView. In that way, Toolbar and/or TabLayout will scroll together with Scrollview